# How to use the feature_names_out with scikit's FunctionTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am trying the use `feature_names_out` on scikit's `FunctionTransformer` to get the same feature names but I get this error:

**Code:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

X = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3], name='numbers')
transformer = FunctionTransformer(np.log, feature_names_out='one-to-one')
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell 8 in <cell line: 5>()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
      4 X = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3], name='numbers')
----> 5 transformer = FunctionTransformer(np.log, feature_names_out='one-to-one')
      7 transformer.transform(X)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'feature_names_out'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the version of **scikit-learn**. `feature_names_out` was added only in version `1.1` so you may need to update `scikit-learn`.

From the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html):

> **feature_names_out : *callable, ‘one-to-one’ or None, default=None***
>
> New in version 1.1.

You can check the version with the following code:

```py
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

or using pip:

```
pip freeze | grep scikit
```